# How to prepare Unicode strings for indexing?

Tags: java, text, indexing, unicode, unicode-normalization

This question refers to normalization of international characters for storing local names in indexes. I would like to discuss the problem in general and also hear about possible existing solutions (classes/libraries) in Java.

---

In a global application, users enter their name and the application writes each name into a search index, so that other users can search for names and find users. Trivial in English, but not so trivial in many other languages and/or on a global scale, as specific letters need to be transliterated and/or can be written in several forms. For example, the German name Häußler may be written as

- Häußler (Germany)
- Haeussler (Germany, international transliteration)
- Häussler (Switzerland)
- Hausler (English transliteration)

Java has the

```
    Normalizer.normalize(entry, Normalizer.Form.NFD) // NFC
```

class, but this seems not to work in many instances and/or I don't know how to properly make use of it. Good read is here as well http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence but I couldn't find enough bundled information about this topic.

Does anybody know of an existing open source project where somebody has worked on that problem already? Any libraries that could be used? Websites?

How do you Japanese, Chinese, Arabs, etc. transliterate your languages into English? How do large social networks like Facebook transliterate their usernames to ensure they can be found internationally?

Comment: Very interesting question... I remember having studied the normalization stuff for another SO question, where the goal was to remove accents (I did that using a regex after decomposing using a `Normalizer`). Internationally, however, even Unicode can not fit the bill, I guess... No idea whether this exists at all, but maybe a library which "translates" text into [IPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA)?

Comment: Also: "Unicode strings" in the title is kind of a redundancy; Java does use Unicode from the get go, even though a `char` is really a UTF-16 code unit (which is why code points outside the BMP require two `char`s -- the reason for this is that when Java was born, Unicode only defined what is known now as the BMP)

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track -- one search term you might want to add is "canonical."

I believe the [ICU project](http://site.icu-project.org) is the most robust open source software that's handled this. Take special interest in the [normalization components](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/normalization), particularly the implementations of NFKC_Casefold, which handle the German ß example among many others.

Comment: Thank you, ICU is a very interesting hint, I will look into this and get back.